# ASIHTTPRequest accept headers (406 error)

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I'm currently playing with the Freckle API in an iOS app and I'm being returned a 406 HTTP error. I tested with some other frameworks and they do return the content presented by the API. But with ASIHTTPRequest, a ’406 Not Acceptable’ error is all I'm getting.

Try doing a GET request to the following url: https://apitest.letsfreckle.com/api/projects.json?token=lx3gi6pxdjtjn57afp8c2bv1me7g89j

I'm wondering why this is happening. Does anyone have an idea why and a possible fix? I'm pretty sure it has to do with accept-headers, though haven't found a way to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"]` ?

Comment: Yes I did try that. But I've used ASIHTTPRequest many times with json API's, so that couldn't be the problem.

Comment: Do you still get the same error is you drop the format altogether and just specify the accept header? `https://apitest.letsfreckle.com/api/projects?token=lx3gi6pxdjtjn57afp8c2bv1me7g89j`

Comment: Changed to your URL and it still gives me the 406 error. Added the accept header, but ASI must've already added it because it always works out of the box.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is at Freckle's end rather than with ASIHttpRequest. One last thing to try, just to see if we can get it working. Hit `https://apitest.letsfreckle.com/api/projects.xml` (*I know you want JSON, but this is just a process of elimination*) but set the following request headers `[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/xml"]` and `[request addRequestHeader:@"X-FreckleToken" value:@"lx3gi6pxdjtjn57afp8c2bv1me7g‌​89j"]`

Comment: If I run that it gives me a 200 code but the contents of login page. In other program: http://freshcreations.be/files/Screen%20shot%202011-07-28%20at%2016.42.22.png (after redirect)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a framework problem. The problem might be with the parameters that you are sending. Or even the header. Send the header as the following method:

```
NSString *headerString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", sesske, sessid];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Cookie" value:headerString]; 

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
```

if you have no header do it as below:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

Check each and every parameter and spelling properly before sending. let me know if that works. If that does not work please give more information on the question like what is the web service that you are trying to call and everything.